# Open Modal popup with Autofocus

Tags: php, css, modal-dialog, href, autofocus

I've The following Code :

```
<a href="#openModal"></a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a href="" title="" class="close">X</a>

<?php 
//PHP code
//PHP code
//PHP code
//PHP code
echo "<center><b> Employee(s) List </b></center>";
echo "<br />";
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

// I NEED AUTOFOCUS HERE
<center>
<a href="cash_employee.php<?php echo "?name=".$row['name'] ?>" class="emp" ><?php echo ucfirst($row['name']) ?></a>
</center>
// I NEED AUTOFOCUS HERE

<?php   
}

echo "<center><a href='' title='' class='close2' onmousedown='location.reload(home.php);'>Close Window</a></center>";
}
else {
echo "<center>";
echo "<font color='red' size='+3'>Sorry!<br /> No Employee(s) Found </font>";   
echo "</center>";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Based on the code above, the output will result list of employee names by which you need to use the mouse to hover and click on the employee name to proceed. What i am looking for is to find a way to insert autofocus option in-order to use keyboad arrow (up or down) then clicking enter. I used this method on different code using `<input type="button" autofocus="autofocus"  >` and it works as needed. But when i change the

`<a href="cash_employee.php<?php echo "?name=".$row['name'] ?>`

to make it look like this

`<input type="button" onclick="window.location('cash_employee.php<?php echo "?name=".$row['name'] ?>')" autofocus="autofocus">` it will not work , but the list of employee names are available.

Is there any alternative way of doing it, I'm afraid Open Modal won't support this option ? 
Please Help Thanks

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This may not be a PHP question. I think the PHP code does not play a role here as the modal window only opens in the client. Please post the HTML output not the PHP code.

Comment: @HerrSerker You have missed the `for loop` part in my code. The lines where it says PHP code is where I need to `SELECT` employee names from mysql table and list them all based on the way shown above WHILE using modal. So yes, PHP is needed for MY question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move your employee list to its own `employeelist.php` file, then place it in your page like so...

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
   <?php include('employeelist.php'); ?>
</div>
```

You can then modify your button to the following...

```
<a id="cashEmployee" href="cash_employee.php<?php echo "?name=".$row['name'] ?>
```

And then in your modal dialog add...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cashEmployee').focus();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this effect using following code. (Uses jQuery).

jQuery:

```
//Add first focus
$("a.active").focus();
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    //Up arrow
    if(e.which == 38){
        var prev = $("a.active");
        //Move focus around
        $("a.active").prev("a.employe").addClass("active").focus();
        prev.removeClass("active");
    }
    //Down arrow
    if(e.which == 40){
        var prev = $("a.active");
        //Move focus around
        $("a.active").next("a.employe").addClass("active").focus();
        prev.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Example html:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('test1')" class='employe'>Test</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('test2')" class='employe'>Test</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('test3')" class='employe active'>Test</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('test4')"class='employe'>Test</a>
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GA756/1/